# TypeError when inserting time into xlsxwriter

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python, xlsxwriter

I'm importing two points of data from MySQLdb.  The second point is a time which cursor.fetchall() returns as a timedelta.  I had no luck trying to insert that info into xlsxwriter, always getting a "TypeError: Unknown or unsupported datetime type" error.

Ok... round 2

Now I'm trying to convert the timedelta into a datetime.datetime object:

```
for x in tempList:
    timeString = str(x[1])
    ctTime.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(timeString,"%H:%M:%S))
```

Now in xlsxwriter, I setup formatting:

```
ctChart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Time', 'name_font': {'size': 14, 'bold': True}, 'num_font': {'italic': True},'date_axis': True})
```

And then I create a time format:

```
timeFormat = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'hh:mm:ss'})
```

Then I attempt to insert data:

```
ctWorksheet.write_datetime('A1',ctTime,timeFormat)
```

But no matter what I do, no matter how I format the data, I always get the following error:

```
TypeError: Unknown or unsupported datetime type
```

Is there something stupidly obvious I'm missing?

*********** EDIT 1 ***********
jmcnamara - In response to your comment here are more details:

I've tried using a list of time deltas such as datetime.timedelta(0, 27453) which when printed is 7:37:33 using the following code:

```
timeFormat = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'hh:mm:ss'})
ctWorksheet.write_datetime('A1',ctTime,timeFormat)
```

I still get the error:  TypeError: Unknown or unsupported datetime type

Even iterating through the list and attempting to insert the results fails:

```
timeFormat = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'hh:mm:ss'})
i = 0
for t in ctTime:
    ctWorksheet.write_datetime(i,0,t,timeFormat)
i += 1
```

Comment: What is the type of `ctTime` when it throws a `TypeError`?

Comment: ctTime itself is a list with elements of datetime.timedelta.

Comment: The `write_datetime()` method doesn't support writing lists. Check the documentation. The `write_row()` method does, so you can try that if you wish or else do a manual loop like in the second part of your updated example. However, as stated below `datetime.timedelta` is only (currently) supported by the GitHub master version of XlsxWriter.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working with my most recent code.  The chart still isn't graphing correctly using the inserted times, but at least they are inserting correctly.

Since I was pulling the timedeltas from SQL, I had to change their format first.  Raw timedeltas from SQL just weren't working:

```
for x in templist:
    timeString = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x[1]),"%H:%M:%S")
    ctTime.append(timeString)
```

With those datetime.strptime formatted times I was able to then successfully insert into the worksheet.

```
timeFormat = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'hh:mm:ss'})
i = 0
for t in ctTime:
    ctWorksheet.write_datetime(i,0,t,timeFormat)
i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The GitHub master version of [XlsxWriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/libxlsxwriter) supports `datetime.timedelta`.

Try it out and let me know if it works. It will probably be uploaded to PyPI in the next week.

Comment: Updated my question with more info in response.  Thank you!